# How to modify 2d array in shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, sh

I have the following sample code for my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

x[1,1]=0
x[2,1]=1

echo "x[1,1]=${x[1,1]}"
echo "x[2,1]=${x[2,1]}"

for i in {1..2}; do
    x[$i,1]=${i}
    echo "loop$i x[$i,1]=${i}"
done

echo "x[1,1]=${x[1,1]}"
echo "x[2,1]=${x[2,1]}"
```

and I am expecting for x[1,1] to have the value of 1 and x[2,2] to have the value of 2.

But when I run the script the result is:

```
$ ./test3.sh    
x[1,1]=1    
x[2,1]=1    
loop1 x[1,1]=1    
loop2 x[2,1]=2
x[1,1]=2    
x[2,1]=2
```

I expect `x[1,1]` to retain the value of 1 but it happens to be 2 now. Is there something wrong with my script?

Answer (score 2):

Bash does not have 2-D arrays.  The best you can do is emulate them with associative arrays.

Add the following line to the beginning of your script:

```
declare -A x
```

This makes `x` into an associative array.  When that is done, the script produces the output that you expect:

```
$ bash script
x[1,1]=0
x[2,1]=1
loop1 x[1,1]=1
loop2 x[2,1]=2
x[1,1]=1
x[2,1]=2
```

#### Bash indexed arrays

Unless `declare -A` is used, a bash array is just an indexed array.  Let's define `y` as an indexed array:

```
$ y=()
```

Now, let's assign two values:

```
$ y[2,3]=1
$ y[22,3]=2
```

Now, let's use `declare -p` to find out what the contents of the array really are:

```
$ declare -p y
declare -a y='([3]="2")'
```

As you can see, there is only `y[3]`.  The reason is that the index in an indexed array is subject to arithmetic expansion and, when given a list of comma-separated values, *arithmetic expansion* returns just the last one.

In other words, as far as bash is concerned, assignments to `y[2,3]` and `y[22,3]` are both just assignments to `y[3]`.  The second assignment overwrites the first.

We can see this directly if we echo the results of arithmetic expansion:

```
$ echo $((3))
3
$ echo $((2,3))
3
$ echo $((22,3))
3
```

When given a list of comma-separated values, arithmetic expansion returns the last one.  This is true even if the comma-separated list is a long one:

```
$ echo $((1+2,3*4,5,6,7,8))
8
```

It is always the last value which is returned.

#### Bash associative arrays

Let's examine what happens with associative arrays.  Let's define `z` as an associative array and assign some values to it:

```
$ declare -A z
$ z[1,2]=1
$ z[3,4]=2
$ z["Jim Bob"]=3
```

Now, let's see what was stored in `z`:

```
$ declare -p z
declare -A z='([3,4]="2" ["Jim Bob"]="3" [1,2]="1" )'
```

This seems to be what you need.

Comment: Thanks! declare -A did the job. I have rechecked other posts I saw about 2d arrays for shell, and I have overlooked declare